# Is there a way to find out if my ImageView is displaying a certain resource in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-image

I have an ImageView that is set to cam.jpg in my XML Layout code:

```
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imvCover"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/cam"
             />
```

Is there a way, in my Java code, to find out if my `imvCover` is currently displaying `@drawable/cam` or something else? Something like this:

```
if (imvCover.displayedImageResource == R.id.cam)
   // do something
else
   // do something else
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use `setTag()` and `getTag()` methods like this :

when setting the drawable resource to your `imageView` do like this :

```
img.setBackgroundResource(R.id.img1);
img.setTag(R.id.img1);
```

and to find out which drawable is setted to your `imageview` , just get the tag ans test it :

```
if(((int)img.getTag() ) == R.id.img1) {
   //do stuff1 here 
}
if(((int)img.getTag() ) == R.id.img2) {
   //do stuff2 here 
}
```